# When a UIImageView's image is set from Interface Builder, how is that image loaded?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiimageview, interface-builder, nsbundle

When an image view's source is pre-set from the attributes inspector, when/how is the actual path to the file resolved? There don't seem to be any calls to NSBundle, but I may be wrong.

EDIT: I'm trying to swizzle whatever method is called (if possible) to dynamically replace the assets later.

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't it just be relative to the bundle that the view controller is in?

Comment: Maybe it calls [UIImage imageNamed:]? I'm not a swizzle ninja so I don't know how you can override that.

Comment: Good guess, but it doesn't seem to use that method.

Comment: Did you find any solutions? None of `pathForResource` and `imageNamed` are getting called... Moreover, `initWithContentsOfFile:` on `UIImage` isn't getting called

Comment: Nope, didn't figure it out

Answer (score 10, accepted):

None of `UIImage` initializers or factories are getting called.
I made some research with debugger (on iOS Simulator 7.0.3) and found following:
1) `UIImageView` which is set up in IB is initialised via `-initWithCoder:`.
2) In `initWithCoder:` method `decodeObjectForKey:` is called. And (!) key named `UIImage` contains image from IB. This image is set to `UIImageView` through ivar, not through `setImage:` setter.
So, seems like IB packs raw image data into XIB / Storyboard while compiling. Nonsense, but true.
That's why we cannot swizzle `+imageNamed:` or some another factory and should use conditional code to setup images for retina4 and iOS6

**EDIT:**

Comments show up that hexdumping of compiled IB file has png name inside.

> In fact, looking at the output of "hexdump -C
>   BYZ-38-t0r-view-8bC-Xf-vdC.nib " indicates that the filename of the
>   PNG appears in the compiled file. So, it must be loading the file data
>   via the file name from the same bundle.

However, they're still loaded via some internal mechanism, not via `imageNamed:`

Comment: Yes...so there is no way to swizzle some method like imageNamed?

Comment: You can swizzle it, but for this particular task, you'll get no profit

Comment: The comment about "IB packs raw image data into XIB" does not make sense. I just looked at a compiled storyboard and found that the image data is not inlined into the output file BYZ-38-t0r-view-8bC-Xf-vdC.nib. In fact, looking at the output of "hexdump -C BYZ-38-t0r-view-8bC-Xf-vdC.nib " indicates that the filename of the PNG appears in the compiled file. So, it must be loading the file data via the file name from the same bundle.

Comment: @MoDJ thanks for your comment, I've updated answer appropriately. However, I'd ask you to treat your wording more carefully. "This does not make sense" is rather abusive than constructive.

Comment: Abusive? Petro, you made an assertion in your writeup that inlining PNG data was "Nonsense, but true." My correcting your mistaken conclusion is not abuse, it is the Socratic method.

Comment: @MoDJ compare my depersonalized statement with yours pointing at exact  mistake of mine.  My almost-3-years-ago research has given these results and feeling sense of good attitude in SO community I would say something like "My research has shown different results" or "Are you sure in your statement because I've compiled and blah-blah". If you don't think that mutual respect is vital here or don't agree with my arguments I appreciate that, because it's something called THE POINT. However, having THE POINT is not enough, one should be able to deliver it in clear and polite way IMO

Comment: @MoDJ also please mind, that my answer has solved OP's problem despite one of assertions inside was false-positive. And the summary is still actual despite on of assertions inside was false-positive. Keeping this in mind, I would correct mistakes on these parts very carefully, probably proposing an edit to an answer, but not commenting something wrong out in the way you did this

Answer (score 3):

iOS will automatically look for your file `overflow.png` in the same bundle as your xib file. If your xib file is just in your application's target, then by default it looks inside the main bundle.

If you want to programatically load a new image into an image view and your image is inside the main bundle:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"MyAwesomeImage"];
self.imageView.image = image;
```

If your image is inside another bundle:

```
NSBundle *imageBundle = ... // [NSBundle mainBundle] if your image is inside main bundle
NSString *imagePath = [imageBundle pathForResource:@"MyAwesomeImage" ofType:@"png"];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
self.imageView.image = image;
```

Comment: Yes, but is there any method called to get the path? (See me edit for motivation).

Comment: @kasrak, You want the path of the image overflow.png? Is it in the main bundle?

Comment: I don't think I was very clear. I'm wondering how the runtime actually initializes the UIImageView when it loads it from the storyboard/xib. This would allow for automatically replacing images in the app without any code changes.

Comment: @andi There is a typo. Try self.imageView.image